# Problema al borrar archivo (imagen) de servidor con unlink

Tags: php, mysql

estoy creando una aplicacion que registra en una tabla mysql los datos de una empresa, entre estos un logo. Funciona perfecto hasta crear, sin embargo cuando intento borrar el archivo (imagen), no se borra. No tengo mensaje de error, nada.

- Intente hacerlo directamente con un documento con el codigo unlink subido al servidos y si funciona.
- Verifique que el usuario de la base de datos tenga todos los permisos de escritura.
- Se borra todo el registro de la base de datos, pero no la imagen en el servidor.

El codigo que deberia borrar la imagen es el siguiente:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
$id = $_POST['id'];
$id = filter_var($id, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

if ($id) {
    $query = "DELETE FROM m_empresa WHERE empresa_id = ${id}";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($db, $query);

    $query = "SELECT empresa_logo FROM m_empresa WHERE empresa_id = ${id}";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($db, $query);

    $empresa = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
    unlink('../build/img_empresa/'. $empresa['empresa_logo']);
    if ($resultado) {
    header('location: /main/empresas.php?conf=3');

    }

}
```

}

El codigo que he usado para crear (subir la imagen) en la carpeta es este (esto mas el query funciona correctamente):

```
    if (!$imagen['name']) {
    $errores[] = "La imágen es obligatoria";
}

//Validar por tamaño, 1MB max
$medida = 1000 * 1000;

if ($imagen['size'] > $medida || $imagen['error']) {
    $errores[] = "El tamaño de la imágen no es adecuado";
}

//Revisar que arreglo de errores este vacío
if (empty($errores)) {
    // Subir Archivos
    //Crear carpeta
    $carpetaImagenes = '../build/img_empresa/';
    if (!is_dir($carpetaImagenes)) {
        mkdir($carpetaImagenes);
    }
    //Generar nombre unico
    $nombreImagen = md5(uniqid(rand(), true)) . ".jpg";

    //var_dump($nombreImagen);

    //Subir la imagen
    move_uploaded_file($imagen['tmp_name'], $carpetaImagenes . $nombreImagen);
```

Comment: te recomendaria mover las imagenes a una carpeta trash ... y vaciarla cada x tiempo con un cron

Answer (score 0):

Tu segunda consulta hace referencia a una empresa que acabas de eliminar en la primera, de ahí que no encuentre el registro. Si cambias el orden, debería funcionar:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $id = filter_var($id, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

    if ($id) {
        $query     = "SELECT empresa_logo FROM m_empresa WHERE empresa_id = ${id}";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($db, $query);
        $empresa   = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);

        $query     = "DELETE FROM m_empresa WHERE empresa_id = ${id}";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    
        if (mysqli_affected_rows($db) > 0) { // Comprueba si se ha borrado una línea usando affected rows, haciéndolo con if ($resultado) siempre va a devolver true, borre o no borre un registro
            unlink('../build/img_empresa/'. $empresa['empresa_logo']);
            header('location: /main/empresas.php?conf=3');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias... se me habia escapado ese pequeño detalle... muy agradecido